# Find the supremum and infimum of $B:=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ without using limits

Tags: real-analysis

If I am supposed to find the infimum and supremum of $B:=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ without using limits is it sufficient to use the fact that $\forall n\in N\Rightarrow n\geq 1\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}\leq 1$ to show that the supremum is 1 and then that $\frac{1}{n}>0$ to show that the infimum is $0$.

Comment: To show that $1$ is the sup you need to show that $1$ is an upper bound (done) and that no number $x < 1$ is also an upper bound (this requires an additional comment). Similarly $0$ is the inf if it is a lower bound (done) and that no $x > 0$ is a low bound (you have not yet shown this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that an upper bound for a set need not be the least upper bound for that set; so what you want to do is not sufficient.

We claim that $\sup B = 1$; let $\varepsilon > 0$. If $\varepsilon \geq 1$, then $n := 1$ is such that $1 - \varepsilon < 1/n \leq 1$; if $\varepsilon < 1$, then $n := \lfloor \frac{1}{1-\varepsilon} \rfloor$ is such that $1 - \varepsilon < 1/n \leq 1$; hence there is always some $n \geq 1$ such that $1- \varepsilon < 1/n \leq 1$, 
and we are done.
In the similar fashion, we have $\inf B = 0$; for $n := \lceil 1/\varepsilon \rceil + 1$ is such that $0 < 1/n < 0 + \varepsilon = \varepsilon$.

Comment: You're working much too hard on the supremum. There's no need to proceed by cases, as $n=1$ always works. That's the nice thing about a maximum, here.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you; I confess that I did not notice that :)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't quite sufficient. That is enough to show that $1$ is *an* upper bound of $B$ (to show it is the least such, just show that $1\in B$) and that $0$ is *a* lower bound of $B$ (to show that it is the greatest such, note that if $x>0,$ then there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n>\frac1x,$ and go from there).

Comment: So to show that the infimum is 0 we take an arbitrary $x>0$ and by the archimedean property $\exists N_x\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N_x\Rightarrow n\geq \frac{1}{x}$ therefore the infimum must be 0?

Comment: That's roughly the idea. You don't need to worry about the universal quantifier, though. Just note that there is an $n_x\in\Bbb N$ such that $n_x>\frac1x.$ Consequently, we can show that $x$ is not a lower bound of $B.$ (Can you see how?)

Comment: Yea I'm pretty sure it follows the fact then that $\forall x >0 \exists n_x$ such that $x>\frac{1}{n_x}$ so we will always be able to find an $n_x$ such that $\frac{1}{n}$ is less than $x$

Comment: Yep! That's it!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to show those are the least and greatest upper and lower bounds respectively. Meaning if $l$ is a greater lower bound, then there is something in the set less than $l$ and same for the other.

Hint: use a consequence of the Archimedian principle for the inf. The sup is not difficult.